# Fill hash with checkboxlist (key) and dropdown (value) doesn't work? In ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am implementing a checkboxlist with some items and next to each item there is a dropdown. These two things hang together and what i want to do is to create a hash, the key is the value or id from the checked item, the value is the value of the selected item in the dropdown.

This is what i have:
view:

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>
      <li>
        <%= check_box_tag 'group[]', group.id -%>
        <%= h group -%>
        <%= select_tag 'role_group[group.id][]', options_for_select(@roles) %>
      </li>
  <% end %>
```

controller:

```
@selected_groups = Group.find(params[:group]) 
  @selected_roles = params[:role_group]

  @roleskeys = @selected_roles.keys
```

Now if i show @roleskeys , he always just say group.id. So this is not correct, this is just the string. Somebody who knows what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>
      <li>
        <%= check_box_tag 'group[][id]', group.id -%>
        <%= h group -%>
        <%= select_tag 'group[][group_id]', options_for_select(@roles) %>
      </li>
<% end %>
```

You will have both together in a Hash.

Comment: Nope this doesn't work, i get the error: Couldn't find all Groups with IDs ('--- !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess \nid: \"9\"\ngroup_id: Anonymous\n','--- !map:HashWithIndifferentAccess \ngroup_id: Manager\n') (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)
Do you know what i am doing wrong now?

Comment: Pleas post `paramas.inspect` of the relevant page

Comment: My parameters are: {"time_tracking"=>"true",
 "group"=>[{"id"=>"9",
 "group_id"=>"Developer"},
 {"id"=>"10",
 "group_id"=>"Developer"}],
 "repository"=>"true",
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "issue_tracking"=>"true"
}

Comment: Ok, i've think i found it.Now i have a hash, but if i don't check the checkbox, there is an error: because there is a value in 1 item, but not the key because it is not selected. WHat do I have to do against that? Thanks

Comment: My parameters then look like : {"group"=>[{"id"=>"9", "group_id"=>"Anonymous"}, {"group_id"=>"Non member"}] and the params[:group] is an array :s ?

Comment: I think your problem is the content of `@roles` would you please post the content of `@roles`. The Problem seems to be that you want the `group_id` but you arent setting the id as the `value` you set the displayed text as `value`.

Comment: roles is filled by models, of class Role, i fill it by @roles = Role.find :all, :order => 'builtin, position'. The output of roles = Manager
Developer
Reporter
Non member
Anonymous

Comment: Why dont you use `collection_select` when there is a relation to a model?

Comment: Does this work in my case? i will give it a try, and try to work that out.

Comment: This doesn't work? do you have other solutions? thanks a lot already!